# Playframework sends 2 queries for fetched query

Tags: caching, jpa, playframework

I currently have problems with the JPA at the play framework 1.2.4.

I need to have a UserOptions model in a separate database and want to join it lazyly cause its only needed in one query.

In this query I want to load the options eagerly and by searching I found out that can only be done by using a join query.

If I use eager instead oder lazy, everything would be fine by using User.findById() and the options and the user is found in one query.

But play sends two queries when I use a 'left join fetch' query. So heres the query:

```
User.find("
    SELECT
        user
    FROM
        User user
    LEFT JOIN FETCH
        user.options options
    WHERE
        user.id = ?
", Long.parseLong(id)).first();
```

And here the models:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model
{

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public UserOptions  options;

    // ...

}

@Entity
public class UserOptions extends Model
{

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public User user;

}
```

The question is why play sends two query for the fetch query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Another question: when I use findById, play caches the request. When I use find with my query, play doesn't. Maybe this is the same issue. How to make Play cache the user?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it myself. The query is still the same.

The problem was, that custom queries are not cached by default. So I used this piece of code to provide a database cache (only for the current request).

```
        // Get database cache instance
        EhCacheImpl cache = EhCacheImpl.getInstance();

        // Get cached user
        User user = (User)cache.get("UserWithOptions_"+id);

        // Check whether a user is cached
        if(user == null)
        {
            // Get the user
            user = User.find("SELECT user FROM User user LEFT JOIN FETCH user.options options WHERE user.id = ?", Long.parseLong(id)).first();
        }

        // Refresh cache
        cache.add("UserWithOptions_"+id, user, 0);
```

May the force be with you!